# Track 2 domains pointing to the same site?

Tags: google-analytics

My web app is available via two domains `example.com` and `example2.com` I created my tracking profile with `example.com` and it works fine. But I am noticing that any visits via `example2.com` are not showing up (at least not in the `Real-Time` feature).

Is there anyway to make analytics recognize both domains as the same property?

I've googled this and only found solutions for 2 completely different websites being tracked in the same profile, not the same website with 2 different domains.

Comment: You should be aware that having two separate domains pointed to the same content (without one being canonical and having the other one redirect to the canonical domain) will result in significant SEO penalties for duplicate content.  Eg you don't want `example.com/page` and `example2.com/page` going to the exact same content... you want `example2.com/page` 301 redirecting to the canonical url `example.com/page`

Answer (score 2):

I assume this document entry on [cross domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) is what you found. Well, it is exactly what you need to do.  "2 completely different websites" means exactly the same as "2 different domains", which is exactly what your situation is. The important 'issue' is that they are on 2 different domains, not what the content is.

Basically, you need to set

`_setDomainName` and `_setAllowLinker` on all your pages of both domains with the proper values, and you also need to include a call to `_link` in all links that point from one domain to the other.

The reason for all this hoop-jumping is because GA uses 1st party cookie tracking and part of the values for the visit(or) tracking are hashed to the domain as a form of security. So you have to set those variables properly and then set `_link` to pass all the cookie info to the other domain so that it can properly use the info to carry the visit(or) through.

All this is for making sure your visit(or) info is not broken.  You *should* be seeing data for both domains as-is, though - the visit(or) just won't carry over.  So you should see page views just fine, but entry and path reports will be messed up, along with metrics and dimension that spread across both sites.  So if you aren't seeing *any* data from `example2.com` then you have an entirely different issue.

1. check to make sure you are pointing to the same GA account in the on-page code
2. make sure you don't have any filters set to exclude/include traffic from anything other than `example1.com`
3. make sure if you are already using `_setDomainName` that it's set to the actual domain the page is on (or the root domain of it). This setting is directly tied to how the cookie is set, and if for example you were setting it to `.example1.com` on  example2.com's page, well your GA tracking will break, because the cookies won't get set.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the whole block of code, not just the " _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-?????']",

When you have two domains pointing to the same web site, you could get hit with a duplicate content penalty in both AdWords and in Google organic search on both sites. When you do this, it's best to determine which is the "official" version and which is the "mirror". Then use the canonical link tag so all pages point to the same site as the authoritative source. It will look something like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/index.html">
```

It goes in the head section of the document.

Best of Luck!